# Print all parameters passed to a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to get all paramters of a PowerShell cmdlet as a hashtable? I want the ability to dump all paramters via `Write-Verbose` (for debugging issues). What I want to do:

```
  Function verb-noun {
      Param($p1, $p2, $p2)

      $parameters = ... # Get all parameters as hash
      $parameters.Keys | % { Write-Verbose "$_=$parameters.Item($_)" } 
      ...
  }
```

Comment: $allArgs = $PsBoundParameters.Values + $args

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable which is a dictionary containing all bound parameter (parameters that you pass to the function)